# Animation_list must be declared error

Tags: android, xml

Having read [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) , [Animation Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame), and other stackoverflow questions, i thought that putting this in the drawable file was the proper way of creating an animation_list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<animation_list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/james_walking_1" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/james_walking_2" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/james_walking_3" android:duration="200"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/james_walking_4" android:duration="200"/>
</animation_list>
```

However , animation_list is red and "must be declared". I dont know what is wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `animation-list`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame), not `animation_list`.

Comment: Already define as animation-list and kept inside anim folder under res directory.Now in which section what goes wrong ,still gives error after successful build of the project.Can anyone explain?

Comment: @blackjack: Please ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] including details about the error.